# Mongoengine Transactions how to?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

How I could do in order to have a transaction that Involves the update of more than two different kind of documents on mongoengine?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean. And show us some code!

Answer (score 7):

Using the following method, you can use the transaction in mongoengine
Note that in this method, your queries must be raw using pymongo

```py
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine.connection import get_connection, get_db

connect('testdb')

class TestDocument(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)


mongo = get_connection()
with mongo.start_session() as session:
    with session.start_transaction():
        try:
            test = TestDocument(name='test')
            mongo.get_database(get_db()).get_collection('test_document').insert_one(
                test.to_mongo(), session=session
            )
            # just for raising an exception
            err = 1 / 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            session.abort_transaction()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a requested mongoengine feature:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1839

A direct pymongo-based workaround is described in the comments.